# Is it better to have html for a javascript web widget in the script or sent from server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, widget

I'm in the process of building a JS widget/script that others can put on their website. The widget will be communicating with my Rails API that I've already built.

Should the html the widget build be in the script (i.e. hard coded in the javascript/jquery) or sent as json from the server?

The MVP of my widget will only have one html template but in the future I would like it to be customizable, so multiple html template options.

**EDIT after Craig's comment:**

The script would be added to a user's site by CDN delivery after they pasted the correct JS snippet to their site.

Comment: without more information this is very difficult to answer, do you want to give a JS file to download, do you want to give a link (ala google analytics) or do you want to have a CDN style delivery ?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @CraigBezuidenhout I updated my question so others would not be confused. The JS would be loaded on the user's site via a CDN style delivery.

Comment: No problem, that makes it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that, I am making the assumption that the user will use something similar to this :

```
<script src="your_awesome_widget_location/the_script_file.js" />
```

in this scenario whether you deliver the html via the javascript or the service is of little consequence.

how often will the layout be updated ?

If not very often , then deliver via javascript as this will be cached and will reduce load on your server.

If very often, then you won't want it cached and the Rails API route is probably better with the JS generating a random key for the request

Comment: Great insight! What do you mean by "...JS generating a random key for the request"?

Comment: a simple example would be <script src="your_awesome_widget_location/the_script_file.js?v={a_random_number_here}" />